# How do I get rid of Syntax error code unexpected token “{“

Tags: node.js

I’m using visual studio code and node js to make a Nft collection. When I type in node index.js I get the syntax error unexpected token “{“.  I know it comes from line 17 but don’t know how to fix it.

SyntaxError: Unexpected tolen
at Object. compileFunction (node:wm: 352:18)
at wrapSafe (node: imternal/modules/cis/loader:1032:15)
at Module. compile (node:internal/modules/cis/loader:1067:27)
at Object.Module, extensions.-js (mode:imternal/modules/cis/loader:11
at Module. load (node: internal/modules/cis/loader:931:32)
at Function.Module, load (node:intermal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Module. require (node: imtermal/modules/cis/loader:1005:19)
at require (node: imtermal/modules/cis/helpers:102:18)
at Object.‹anorymous» (C: WUsers\Tim\OneDriveNDesktopWhashlips art ene

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the relevant code and the full error.

Comment: it means you missed or have an extra "{" at line 17